# how does angular 6 process simultaneously different calls?

Tags: angular, asynchronous, concurrency, angular6

How does angular 6 handle calling multiple calls at the same time?
Say I display two numbers on the same page, returned by two different calls to a web API (subscriptions to Observables).

One of my calls from that page is delayed, how can I determine if this is blocked by another call (most likely the reason, I think), can this be prevented and how?

Is this the expected behavior when two or several calls happen at the same time, angular doesn't treat them in parallel? (i don't use forkJoin, I have two separate subscriptions to two different Observables)

If one of the results is delayed (service takes long to respond), is the second expected to be delayed too?

Comment: Angular can handle multiple calls in parallel. Your question is not clear, please provide some code and also what you already tried. You can use the browser devtools network tab to have a better understanding of what's happening.

Comment: I see a lot of question-marks. Please read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [how to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) first.

Answer (score 0):

Angular doesn't handle several calls, you do.

HTTP calls are made through ReactiveXJS, the library that provides Observables.

To determine your loading strategy, you will use operators.

For instance, the most common ones are

**Merge** : will display values as they array, regardless of the order

```
callOne().pipe(merge(value => callTwo()).subscribe(value => console.log(value));
```

**concat** : will wait for the first one to finish

```
concat(callOne(), callTwo()).subscribe(value => console.log(value));
```

**mergeMap** : will subscribe to second call everyTime a value is received by the first call

```
callOne().pipe(mergeMap(valueOne => callTwo())).subscribe(valueTwo => console.log(valueTwo));
```

**switchMap** : will subscribe to second call everyTime a value is received by the first call, but will cancel the previous subscription to the second call

```
callOne().pipe(switchMap(valueOne => callTwo())).subscribe(valueTwo => console.log(valueTwo));
```

There are A LOT of operators so I won't cover them all, but [this page has them](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/) so feel free to check it out.